# How do I unsubscribe from a post on ubuntu wiki?

Tags: ubuntu-wiki

I want to unsubscribe from a post on Ubuntu's wiki: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/. I can't find how to do that (I found this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HelpOnSubscribing but is does not seem to apply).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Home?action=userprefs&sub=notification, you will see a text box with pages subscribed:

[image]

In my case, I have only subscribed to `Home`. Delete the relevant line(s) and save.

Comment: I see. I have nothing in that box and I still got a notification today for a page I unsubscribed from on Tuesday. The only thing that comes to my mind that I have used multiple accounts to edit pages in the past, but that seems unlikely as I have only one launchpad account as far as I know:-/.

Comment: @sup Then I don't know what to do. Maybe try subscribing again and unsubscribing? I hope I don't get plagued by emails now.

Comment: Hm, I hope not too! I followed your suggestions and I will see if anything changes. It is not a big deal, I thought I was missing something obvious, so accepting your answer.